# What is the minimum number of bytes required to store the sum of two primitive integers?

Tags: encoding-scheme, storage

## Motivation

An informal way word this question is,

> How would re-do some of the weird promotion rules in languages descended from **C**, like **C#** or **Java**. The goal would as to minimize human bewilderment when you add a signed integer (element of $\mathbb{Z}$) to an unsigned integer (an element of $\mathbb{N}$) ..

However, we really want the engage the math side of things to answer this question, with the minimum amount of computer programming jargon.

---

## More Details

In several of the programming languages inspired by **C** have some unexpected behavior when you add a natural number to a negative integer.

In **C** we have something like $(+20) + (-4) = 97128371823$ instead of $(+20) + (-4) = (+16)$.

We sometimes get very strange results with **C** and some of the programming languages compiled into **C**.

Alternatively worded, when you add an `unsigned` and a `signed` together, the output is ***not*** usually what the programmer expected.

Under-the-hood, integers are stored in 8 bits, or 16 bits, or 32 bits, etc... If 8 bits is not enough space, a person can write code "*promote*" the 8-bit integer to a 16 bit integer.

The following are three of the **C++** primitive types:

| Black Board Bold | type name | number of bytes | can be a negative number? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $\mathbb{N}$ | `unsigned` | ***n*** | **no** |
| $\mathbb{Z}$ | `long` | ***2n*** | **yes** |
| $\mathbb{Z}$ | `signed` | ***n*** | **yes** |

When adding a signed 8 bit number to an unsigned 8 bit number we could store the result in a 16 bit signed number.

I have written assembly language before, and I am familiar with the difficulties, don't worry too much about the computer programming aspects of the problem.

---

## Was there a Question in there somewhere?

An answer to this question is a mathematical description of a function named $\mathcal{add}$ (for "*addition*"), which takes two ***primitive specifications*** as input and outputs a new ***primitive specification*** the minimum number of bits required to store the two ***primitive specifications*** added together in the worst case.

### Definition of a ***intspec***

> We define a ***primitive specification*** $p$ to be be an ordered pair $(p.sign, p.bits)$ such that
>
> - $p.sign$ is something like a string taken from the set $\{\mathtt{ℤ}, \mathtt{ℕ}\}$
> - $p.bits$ is a number of bits.

If there is a plus sign, it is unsigned.

If there is a minus sign, the specification is for signed numbers.

---

### Examples of a ***primitive specification***

---

#### Example One

$p_{1} (ℤ, 8)$.

$p_{1}$ is said to be `unsigned` because it represents a natural number taken from $\mathbb{N}$

$p_{1}$ represents positive integers stored in 8 bits.

These integers range from $0$ to $+256$

---

#### Example Two

$p_{2} = (ℕ, 8)$.

a ***signed*** integer stored in 8 bits using the two's compliment system.

$p_{2}$ is a specification for primitive integers ranging from $-128$ to $+127$

In general, `signed` data-types range from $(-1)*2^{n-1}$ to $(-1) + (+1)*2^{n-1}$  where $n$ is the number of bits.

---

## The $\mathcal{add}$ Function

An answer to this question is an algebraic formula for the $\mathcal{add}$ function such that for any two ***intspecs*** $p_{1}, p_{2}$ we have $\mathcal{add}(p_{1}, p_{2})$ equal to the minimum number of bits required to store a number stored using primitive specification $p_{1}$ and primitive specification $p_{2}$.

In other words, $\mathcal{add}(p_{1}, p_{2})$ is a new integer specification containing the minimum number of bits required to add two integers such that the integers are stored using different encoding schemes.

- `(signed)` + `(signed)` will output a signed two's compliment number.
- `(signed)` + `(unsigned)` will output a signed two's compliment number.
- `(unsigned)` + `(unsigned)` will output an unsigned number.

Let $p_{1} = (ℤ, 8)$.  `unsigned` $p_{1}$ ranges from $0$ to $+256$

Let $p_{2} = (ℕ, 8)$.  `signed` $p_{2}$ ranges from $-128$ to $+127$

Consider the worst-case scenarios for adding the two.

In the mathematical sense, output should range from $-128$ to $+383$.

$\mathcal{add}(p_{1}, p_{2}) = (ℤ, 9)$

The output is signed ($ℤ$) and ranges from $-512$ to $+511$.

There are $9$ bits.

$(-1)*2^{9} = -512$

$(-1)+(+1)*2^{9} = +511$

---

## In general, what is a mostly algebraic formula for $\mathcal{add}(p_{1}, p_{2})$?

We want to know what would have to happen when you add a signed integer to an unsigned integer so that the result is what a mathematician would like to see, not an unexpected result.

We want  $(+20) + (-4) = (+16)$, as it should be, instead of ugly non-sense such as $(+20) + (-4) = 97128371823$

Comment: "In C we have something like (+20)+(−4)=97128371823 instead of (+20)+(−4)=(+16)". Can't reproduce: https://onlinegdb.com/FuZVWg0J8

Comment: Did you mix up the $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ symbols in your two examples?

Comment: A byte cannot range from $0$ to $256$ and $(+20)+(−4)=97128371823$ does not arise !

Comment: "a mostly algebraic formula": what ??

Answer (score 0):

C is not designed with a principle of minimal bewilderment, so you'd be talking about a very different language.  (I suppose you could say that C was designed, more or less, to be a portable assembly language, or a step above assembly language.)

If you care about minimal bewilderment, use bigints, like Python.

Answer (score 0):

Signed is from $-2^{b-1}$ to $2^{b-1}-1$ and unsigned from $0$ to $2^b-1$.

Hence assuming the same $b$ for both operands

- signed + signed: $-2^b$ to $2^b-2$, takes $b+1$ bits, signed
- signed + unsigned: $-2^{b-1}$ to $3\cdot2^{b-1}-2$, takes $b+2$ bits, signed
- unsigned + unsigned: $0$ to $2^{b+1}-2$, takes $b+1$ bits, unsigned

[Two's complement convention assumed]

---

Homogeneous addition fits naturally with the numerical representation and is supported natively by the processors, possibly with an overflow bit. Heterogeneous addition is wonky.